# Do we need NGRX for any angular development?

Tags: asp.net, angular, redux, ngrx

Are we always required to implement NGRX/Redux design pattern in any angular development?

I understand redux concept very well, as well as practising the tutorials, however I do not understand how to implement NGRX for my future project.

Comment: It is not mandatory.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omnwu_etHTY

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't need.

As the angular university blog says:

> In Angular we have a whole set of built-in solutions to handle complex
>   component interaction scenarios. The core of all those  solutions is
>   the Angular Dependency Injection system:
>
> 1. We can inject services deep in the component tree if we want to.
> 2. We can even inject components or services into each other if we  feel they are inherently tightly coupled.
> 3. We can create shared data services that might or might not store the data.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/

Comment: Thank you, however can NGRX be implemented in the later stage once my application scales up?

Comment: Yes, it can, but you have to build a project structure that helps you to carry it later.

Comment: Thanks, any reference where to start learning NGRX perhaps?
I recon it is a good practice to start learning NGRX despite more coding required